# gRaphael plugin best practices

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for best practices when creating a plugin for [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/). I'm looking for something like jquery where in its documentation you have the best practices of how to write a plugin. So far I haven't found nothing so I'm starting to imagine that it just comes down to best practices with javascript and not with a particular order of the code or configurability... any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right. I had seen that documentation before. I  am using raphael and do thing it rocks. thanks nick

Comment: @Nick you should convert your comment into an answer, so climboid can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

On the home page at raphaeljs.com there is links for documentation, user group, and Twitter. What more do you need? It's a neat library with what seems like a small group of users compared to other libraries such as jQuery, sounds like you're on your own.